# How to get GPS location on application ported from android to BB10?

Tags: android, geolocation, blackberry-10

My problem is i am not able to get `network or GPS location` when `BB10 Device` is in sleep mode.My device is `Q10 Dev Alpha C` i have done following testing.

- Added run_when_backgrounded permission
- left application running in background.
- logcat is showing its requesting for location update.
- but location is not coming when device is in sleep mode.

same problem has been reported [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-World-Development/GPS-stops-sending-amp-receiving-when-BB10-devices-go-dim-or-into/td-p/2425517)

permission added are using custom `MANIFEST.MF`

```
access_internet,access_shared,access_pimdomain_contacts,play_audio,post_notification,run_when_backgrounded,access_location_services
```